# HTML email - image in email only display at certain devices

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, electronic-direct-mail

In my EDM, I have a few images inside, Its all look good in my desktop and mobile. But when I try to send to other phone devices, some images are not displayed (not found). All the images already hosted to my server. I have referred and follow this [template](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/email-templates.html)  and still the image not displayed.

[image]

```
<p class="desc_email" style="cursor: pointer; text-align: center;" >
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><input type="image" src="https://asd/asd/asd/asd/button.png" style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn" /></a></p>
```

Comment: Wherever you have hosted the files, is it accessible for public? Secondly please post your code so someone can see if your code has issues.

Comment: @Syfer ya, all the images are accessible for public. there are 1500lines of code, so I didn't show it out

Comment: updated question

Comment: You are using an input to style as a link. Just you the image and place an anchor around it. Inputs have very limited support in email world.

Comment: @Syfer yaya I followed your advise, changed it to `img`  and it works now

Comment: @Syfer btw can you help me with this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994811/html-email-the-href-attribute-did-not-hidden-in-some-devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p class="desc_email" style="cursor: pointer; text-align: center;">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="https://asd/asd/asd/asd/button.png" alt="" 
  style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn"></a>
</p>
```

Comment: can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994811/html-email-the-href-attribute-did-not-hidden-in-some-devices