# HTML email - The href attribute did not hidden in some devices

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, electronic-direct-mail

In my EDM, I have:

```
<p class="my_class" style="cursor: pointer; text-align: center;" >
<a href="{{$my_variable}}" style="font-weight:bold;color:#2897FC;">Verify email</a></p>
```

It should look like:

[image]

but this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in [Office 365 and Outlook.com](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/10). When you have any content other than a URL inside a href, Office 365 and Outlook.com will show this content inside the email between brackets. So the following example…

```
<a href="Hello">world</a>
```

… would become :

```
[Hello]world
```

The only walk around is to ***send tests*** with URL's. When actual sends are done the URL gets populated thru the database or content blocks.

Example during tests you will send tests as:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" style="font-weight:bold;color:#2897FC;">Verify email</a></p>
```

Comment: means that if my `$my_variable` is an url then everything should be fine? it will look like usual?

Comment: Yes as soon as the merge tag is populated with an actual url, it will render fine.

Comment: I have tried put an url inside the tag `{{https://www.google.com/}}`,but it show error, is this because of the curly braces? `{{}}`

Comment: The URL will replace the curly brackets as well. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: so when I try I should try this `<a href="https://www.google.com/"` or this `<a href="{{https://www.google.com/}}"`

Comment: Use the one without curly brackets